# Can orderedStructure in .net delete variables if they are compared controversially?

Tags: .net

```
#pragma strict
public class TEffectComparator implements IComparer
{
    public function TEffectComparator()
    {

    }
    public function Compare (f:Object,s:Object)
    {

        if(f.type>s.type)
            return 1;
        else if(f.type<s.type)
            return -1;
        return 1; //Will it cause errors?
    }
}
```

I want to implement a priority queue.

I don't want to implement a special id property.

If my comparison function returns 1 each time when two objects are equal, will it cause errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might.

The implicit contract you sign when implementing `IComparer` (generic or not) is that you behave according to the conventions, which is that you should not return 1 for equal elements.

[Documentation: IComparer.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare.aspx):

> Less than zero means that x is less than y.
>   Zero means that x equals y.
>   Greater than zero means that x is greater than y.

If you're using knowledge that you cannot get from looking at either x or y, you're risking an inconsistent ordering.

Specifically, different sorting implementations in .NET might be optimized to not ask the comparer object for every comparison if it already "knows" the results.

Also note that a comparer should be reflexive and symmetric, which means the following tests should pass:

1. `compare(x, y) == 0` implies `compare(y, x) == 0`, and vice versa
2. `compare(x, y) < 0` means that `compare(y, x) > 0`, and opposite
3. `compare(x, y) < 0` and `compare(y, z) < 0` implies that `compare(x, z) < 0`

Your implementation fails at least nbr. 2, and depending on the order you compare, it will fail nbr. 3.

So it might not *error*, in the sense that it will throw an exception. It might, but it might not. It will probably not order the collection in any meaningful way however.

In your specific case, if the comparer is asked if object `a` is before object `b`, and they seem equal according to your rules, you will return 1 (meaning b before a). Then later, for whatever reason, the code asks your comparer if object `b` is before object `a`, and they're still equal, you still return 1 (meaning a before b), you will get inconsistent results.